# how to implement an if entry exist overwrite rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement some sort of uniqueness in my database with the option to replace current value if it is already in the database.

My table looks like

```
t.integer  "task_id"
t.integer  "accessor_id"
t.integer  "access_owner"
t.boolean  "access_rights"
```

and I want to check that if there is an entry with task_id, accessor_id and access_owner than update access_right, and if there isn't one create such entry

my current create method and new method are

```
class AccessorsController < ApplicationController
 def new
      @accessor = Accessor.new
      @task_id = params[:task_id]
  end


  def create
    @accessor = Accessor.new(accessor_params)
    @user = User.where(email: params[:accessor][:accessor_id]).first
    @accessor.accessor_id = @user.id    
    @accessor.access_owner = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @accessor.save
        format.html { redirect_to Task, notice: 'User was successfully created.' } #
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: Task }#
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' } #
        format.json { render json: @accessor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }#
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried to do the following

```
@accessor = Accessor.where("access_owner = ? AND accessor_id = ? AND task_id = ?", current_user.id, User.where(email: params[:accessor][:accessor_id]).first,params[:task_id]).first || Accessor.new(accessor_params)
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_or_initialize_by..` methods:

```
@accessor = Accessor.find_or_initialize_by_task_id_and_accessor_id_and_access_owner(params[:task_id], params[:accessor_id], params[:access_owner])

@accessor.update_attributes(
   :access_rights => params[:access_rights]
)
```

Comment: will this be added before the save? or will it replace some of my method?

Comment: update_attributes saves the record. You can just set the attribute first, and then save it. 
 \@accessor.access_rights = params[:access_rights]
 \@accessor.save
I will update my answer with create method you will have.

Comment: Looking forward to see this, as you can see in my update I creates a new entry with a nil value